# Formula for mouse wheel step distance

Tags: user-interface, scrollbar, formula

Help me get the formula that calculates the distance for one step of the mouse wheel.
[image]
For different content heights I get different distances per mouse wheel step, here are my measurements:

```
Content height: 1540 px
Viewport height: 730 px
Thumb height: 346 px
Mouse wheel step distance: 30 px

Content height: 1078 px
Viewport height: 730 px
Thumb height: 494 px
Mouse wheel step distance: 26 px

Content height: 1001 px
Viewport height: 730 px
Thumb height: 532 px
Mouse wheel step distance: 24 px
```